# Prove $x^4 + 131 = 3y^4$ has no integer solutions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I tried proving that $\dfrac{\Delta}{4}$ isn't a perfect square, but reducing it modulo 4 doesn't lead anywhere. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $\mod 5{}$

Comment: @Wojowu But there can be a situation where $x^4 + 131 \equiv 2 \pmod 5$ and $3y^4 \equiv 2 \pmod 5$

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: @Wojowu I honestly have no idea :P I just did the congruence calculation and arrived at the conclusion.

Comment: Redo your calculation. By Fermat's little theorem, $y^4\equiv 0$ or $1\pmod 5$, so $3y^4\equiv 0,3\pmod 5$.

Comment: $x^4 + 131 \equiv x^4 + 1 \equiv 2,0 \pmod 5 \: \: 3y^4 \equiv 3 \cdot 1, 3 \cdot 4 \equiv 3 , 2 \pmod 5$

Comment: $y^4$ can't be $4\pmod 5$.

Comment: @Wojowu $(p + 2)^2 \equiv 4 \pmod 5$ right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44953/discussion-between-wojowu-and-airdish).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$x^4\equiv0,1\pmod5$ for $x\in\Bbb Z$ and $131\equiv1\pmod5$. We now reduce the equation modulo 5 and check four cases, but all turn out to be impossible:
$$0+1\not\equiv3\cdot0\pmod5$$
$$0+1\not\equiv3\cdot1\pmod5$$
$$1+1\not\equiv3\cdot0\pmod5$$
$$1+1\not\equiv3\cdot1\pmod5$$
$$x^4+131\not\equiv3y^4\pmod5$$
Hence the equation has no integer solution.